# PHP | Remove Blanks between HTMLTags after translating via Bing API

Tags: php, html, replace, tags, bing-translator-api

i got an Problem, i translating some stuff trought the Bing Translator API.
The Text also contains HTML Tags in the most strings, my problem is that Bing add Blanks between HTML Tags, so i get a text like this:

```
Desculpe, nós não poderíamos encontrar um produto combinando sua solicitação de pesquisa. < br / >< forte > tente novamente? < / strong >
```

So my Question is: How can i remove the Whitespaces from the HTML Tags?
I tried it with php's preg_ functions, but nothing what i done solved my problem, hope for your help guys.

Comment: Can I ask you, why do you want to do it? Do you want to keep the HTML tags?

Comment: I mean, if yes, what will you do with `<ahref="/somelink"style="padding:10px"class="someclass"rel="somerel"role="somerole">` for example?

Comment: Please provide an "after" example showing what you want the lines to look like after they are manipulated to remove white space.

Comment: Desculpe, nós não poderíamos encontrar um produto combinando sua solicitação de pesquisa. <br/><forte> tente novamente? </strong>
-
i dont know hot to transform the HTML Tags. My Webserver didnt understand tags like < br /> it get directly displayed. So i need a function that remove the Blanks from the Html Tags.
@lolka_bolka: there are just simple elements like <b>,<i> etc jsu

Answer (score 1):

If there are only single whitespaces 'corrupting' your html, try sth like this:

```
$text = str_replace(["< / ","< "], ["</", "<"], $text);
$text = str_replace([" / >", " >"], ["/>", ">"], $text);
```

But maybe there is a more flexible solution with a regex...